# text copied to excel sheet appear as image

Tags: excel, image, csv, text

An excel sheet I have contains several cells with what was supposed to be text(that was copied from websites), but in fact the cell content behaves like some kind of image that allows to select the text contained within it. I want to export the excel sheet as a CSV file but the content of these cells cannot be exported. Since there are hundreds of cells with this problem, I wonder if there's a quick way of turning all those image-text hybrids into plain text so they can be exported to a txt/CSV properly.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The 'odd' cell content type turned out to be *Excel Shape*. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260173/3682881) below did the trick.

Comment: You'll need to explain a little more, or include exact steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going out on a limb a bit here, and for which the assumption may or may not help.

With acknowledgement to Tim's comment, I am assuming that the text 'containers' are Excel Shapes and located in the active worksheet.

This code will extract the text from each shape and place it in a blank cell near the top-left cell of the shape, before deleting the shape.  It does not differentiate by shape nor recognise if the shapes are contained within groups, nor put the extracted text in a list.  But, if it helps you can refine the code accordingly.

```
Sub textFromShapes()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim shpLoc As String

    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        With shp
            shpLoc = .TopLeftCell.Address
                Do Until Range(shpLoc) = ""
                    shpLoc = Range(shpLoc).Offset(1, 0).Address
                Loop
                Range(shpLoc) = .TextFrame.Characters.Text
                .Delete
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Philip - that's great!  In that case would you please accept the answer by clicking the 'tick' checkmark.